# Session is closed on spring bean with @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session

I am starting a new thread to do some hard work. So I've created a Spring bean that extends Thread like this:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class AtualizaMovimentacoesThread extends Thread{
    @Inject
    MovimentacoesService service;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        movimentacoesService.atualizarEleEFilhos(...);
    }
}
```

So, the MovimentacoesService bean do the hard work.

```
@Component
@Service
public class MovimentacoesCastor implements MovimentacoesService {

    @Override
    @Transactional()
    public void atualizarEleEFilhos(...) {
    }
}
```

But, when atualizarEleEFilhos executes, I'm getting no session or session was closed exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-20" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: br.com.opatecnologia.castor.domain.Lancamento.cobrancas, no session or session was closed
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:122)
at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.isEmpty(PersistentSet.java:169)
at br.com.opatecnologia.castor.domain.Lancamento.getCobranca(Lancamento.java:277)
at br.com.opatecnologia.castor.domain.Lancamento.getDataVencimento(Lancamento.java:915)
at br.com.opatecnologia.castor.service.impl.MovimentacoesCastor.atualizarEleEFilhos(MovimentacoesCastor.java:518)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy112.atualizarEleEFilhos(Unknown Source)
at br.com.opatecnologia.castor.util.AtualizaMovimentacoesThread.run(AtualizaMovimentacoesThread.java:52)
```

Spring and Hibernate log, says that the transaction and session were opened:

```
14:47:19,454 DEBUG [DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
14:47:19,454 DEBUG [JpaTransactionManager] Creating new transaction with name     [br.com.opatecnologia.castor.service.impl.MovimentacoesCastor.atualizarEleEFilhos]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
14:47:19,454 DEBUG [SessionImpl         ] opened session at timestamp: 15085180394
14:47:19,454 DEBUG [JpaTransactionManager] Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@7d218878] for JPA transaction
14:47:19,454 DEBUG [JDBCTransaction     ] begin
14:47:19,454 DEBUG [ConnectionManager   ] opening JDBC connection
14:47:19,454 DEBUG [JDBCTransaction     ] current autocommit status: false
14:47:19,456 DEBUG [JpaTransactionManager] Initiating transaction rollback
14:47:19,456 DEBUG [JpaTransactionManager] Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@7d218878]
14:47:19,456 DEBUG [JDBCTransaction     ] rollback
14:47:19,456 DEBUG [JDBCTransaction     ] rolled back JDBC Connection
14:47:19,456 DEBUG [ConnectionManager   ] aggressively releasing JDBC connection
14:47:19,456 DEBUG [ConnectionManager   ] releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
14:47:19,457 DEBUG [JpaTransactionManager] Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@7d218878] after transaction
```

Am I missing something?

Ps: I inject AtualizaMovimentacoesThread normally in a controller and call start to execute the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I'm passing to atualizarEleEFilhos, an object loaded by hibernate, outside the thread, that explains LazyInitializationException

So, I simply reload the object and everything works now! :D